# Ansible on Windows 10 - pip install missing pycrypto>=2.6

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, ansible

I've installed ansible on Windows 10 + cygwin using pip. The install finished OK, no error on the output. However, when running `ansible` from the cygwin prompt after the install I get:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pycrypto>=2.6' distribution was not found and is required by ansible
```

`pip list` shows that pycrypto is installed in version 2.6.1.

**What can I do to fix this error?**

I have python 2.7.10, pip 8.1.2 and `pip list` prints:

```
ansible (2.1.0.0)
cffi (1.6.0)
cryptography (1.4)
enum34 (1.1.6)
idna (2.1)
ipaddress (1.0.16)
Jinja2 (2.8)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
paramiko (2.0.0)
pip (8.1.2)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pycparser (2.14)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pycryptodome (3.4)
PyYAML (3.11)
setuptools (23.0.0)
six (1.10.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was due to wrongly configured paths, with two installs of Python in the system. I have a pure Windows install as well one installed by Cygwin. Correctly pointing the `Path`, `PYTHON` and `PYTHONPATH` variables the Cygwin install fixed the issue.